# variable seems to be uninitialized but it is showing that exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

new to php here :)

So the problem is that I want to write data from table to view page but it's show warning that variable is not initialized...
( in table News there is column Type and Date  )
Controller function:

```
function ShowNews(){
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('user');
    $q = $this->user->getNews();
    if($q){
        $data['v'] = $q;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

In Model function getNews

```
function getNews(){
    $q = $this->db->get('News');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        return $q->result();
    }
}
```

and in view

```
     <?php if(isset($v)) : foreach( $v as $row) : ?>
         <li><?php echo $row->Type; ?>
          <?php echo $row->Date; ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php else :?>
           <li>No new News</li>
      <?php endif;?>
```

but it's always show No new News and that variable v is uninitialized so I presume that somehow need to initialized v for it to work... and also when i put $ it is show that it exist???

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your `$v` is but you can change the `isset` to an `empty` check:

```
<?php if(!empty($v)) : foreach( $v as $row) : ?>
```

For more information about what is an empty variable check the [empty function manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: $v is this $data['v'] = $q; it's supposed to be a single variable so i can access from a view.. try empty but getting same result

Comment: Your `$q` must be an iterable object then. Otherwise your `foreach` makes no sense.